# Selenium2: bug with Interaction with an element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, behat, mink

I am writing Behat/Selenium2 tests and I want to check a checkbox on the page I test but I got this error :

```
When I check "id_checkbox_role_module_keyword"
      Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

However I can see my checkbox :

[image: checkbox]

And this is my DOM :

```
<div class="checkbox check-success">
    <input type="checkbox" id="id_checkbox_role_module_keyword" name="name" value="ROLE_MODULE_KEYWORD" />
    <label for="id_checkbox_role_module_keyword"><i class="fa fa-line-chart" title="ROLE_MODULE_KEYWORD" data-toggle="tooltip"></i>
                ROLE_MODULE_KEYWORD</label>
</div>
```

Moreover what is weird is that if I test `Then I should see "ROLE_MODULE_KEYWORD"`, the test passes, so selenium2 is seeing this checkbox :

[image: image2]

What's weird is that I have those same checkboxes on an other page and if I execute the same test on the other page, it is completely validated and I don't understand why because both pages have the same HTML.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: can u post the code where u r trying to enable that checkbox

Comment: It's `When I check "ROLE_MODULE_KEYWORD"` in the second screenshot. Behind the curtains, it executes the following code : https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension/blob/master/src/Behat/MinkExtension/Context/MinkContext.php#L153